# BashScript move files based on matching part of filenames from a list

Tags: bash, filenames

I have millions of xml files.  The name of the xml file follows this pattern:

```
ABC_20180912_12345.xml
ABC_20180412_98765.xml
ABC_20180412_45678.xml
```

From this I want to copy files to a different folder based on the name it has after the underscore.  To identify the files, I have a list which I have saved in a csv file which provides me with the required names. An example:

```
vcfile="/home/mycomp/Documents/wd/vehicles.csv"
vcpvr=`cat $vcfile`
```

echo $vcpvr provides me with this list:

```
2894 4249 5464
```

I am able to loop through the xmlfiles in the folder, open each file and grep to see if the file contains the string and if it is, the move the files to a new location. This is working.

The complete code:

```
#filesToExtract is the interim folder
fold="/home/mycomp/filesToExtract";
query=$fold/*.xml

vcfile="/home/mycomp/Documents/wd/vehicles.csv"
vcpvr=`cat $vcfile`

#xmlfiles - keep all tar.gz files here
cd ~/xmlfiles/
COUNTER=1
for f in *.tar.gz
do
echo " $COUNTER "
  tar zxf "$f" -C ~/filesToExtract
  for k in $query
  do
   file $k | if grep -q "$vcpvr"
   then
   mv $k  ~/xmlToWork/
   fi
   done
#xmltowork is the final folder
#rm -r ~/filesToExtract/*.xml
COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
done
```

But since this looks for the string inside the file, instead of filename, it takes longer to process millions of files.  Instead, I want to look for the string in the filename and if it is there, move the files.  This is what I have tried:

```
target="/home/mycomp/xmlToWork"

 for k in $query
  do
  if [[ $k =~ "$vcpvr" ]]; then 
    cp -v $k $target
  fi
  done
```

But this gives me an error `tarextract.sh: 12: tarextract.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: `[[: not found` -> you are not running `bash`.

Comment: can u share how the vehiles.csv file looks like is it just numbers separated by spaces??

Comment: @Index yes..it is just numbers with each number in a subsequent cell / line.  Think of excel - all the numbers are in first column without header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just fine, although I was hesitant to suggest as it will be a slower approach as it involve iteration, but certainly faster than looking into the files.

```
nn=($(cat vehicles.csv));for x in "${nn[@]}";do ls *.xml|grep "$x"|xargs -I '{}' mv {} folder/;done
```

multiline version of the same will be:

```
nn=($(cat test.csv))
for x in "${nn[@]}"
do
ls *.xml|grep "$x"|xargs -I '{}' mv {} /home/inderss/dumps/
done
```

Comment: Thank you...when I tried the code....I got Bad Substitution error for line 2..and when I replaced ${nn[@]} with $nn, i could echo all the numbers of $x....but when I used the 4th line..ie...ls *.xml I could sense the machine takes time to read each file...but the output is missing...however, when I try by replacing $x with just a single number...the code in line 4 works....for example if i hard code $x=2252...it moves all the files that has 2252....I just could not figure out why the for loop is not working

Comment: Thanks a ton for your support.  I have created few dummy files and a test csv here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SJ-zQz-JFHR_scmr7ZAkfIQxwP-yTslV

Comment: @Apricot -I argument after xargs was off there will be no space in that

Comment: I ran the edited code with the test.csv as provided in the link, it worked perfectly fine. bash version= `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: my most sincere apologies for making rookie mistakes

Comment: Thanks a million...the code works....for the life of me I couldn't figure out why it was not running earlier...in fact i have removed the space between the - and `I` earlier....tried many combinations....however this works....thanks a ton again.